Loss GPS EXIF Data for upload image via android app (WebChromeClient)
So, we build some android app (Android 10+) for website. And we have function to create item profile that base on GPS data of EXIF Image of during uploading image. On our app we use WebChromeClient class for allows interraction beetwen WebView and the Android application. So, we have some problem during uploading image: loss gps data of EXIF image. Please, help me with it.
P.S.: Read GPS Exif Data works if website is opened in browser, not android app.
//HTML: field for selecting files on website
<input type="file" name="images[]" accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg;capture=camera" multiple class="upload up form-control" id="up3" required>

//Code From MainActivity.java

private void setupWebView() {
        myWeb = findViewById(R.id.myWeb);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWeb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false); // To disable the zoom control buttons
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true); // Enable viewport support
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); // Fit content to WebView

        myWeb.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        myWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                // Save the callback for later use
                if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null); // Cancel the previous callback
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                // Create an Intent to pick files
                Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();

                // Optionally, restrict the file type here if you want to limit to images:
                // intent.setType("image/*");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    mFilePathCallback = null;
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  // Call super at the start

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                Uri[] results = null;

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        String dataString = data.getDataString();
                        ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();

                        // Handle multiple file selection
                        if (clipData != null) {
                            results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                results[i] = clipData.getItemAt(i).getUri();
                                // Optionally read EXIF data here for each Uri if needed
                                readExifData(results[i]);
                            }
                        } else if (dataString != null) {
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                            // Read EXIF data for single selection
                            readExifData(results[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
                mFilePathCallback = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void readExifData(Uri imageUri) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(inputStream);
                String latitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
                String latitudeRef = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
                String longitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
                String longitudeRef = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);

                if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
                    double lat = convertToDegree(latitude);
                    if ("S".equals(latitudeRef)) {
                        lat = -lat; // Convert to negative for Southern Hemisphere
                    }

                    double lon = convertToDegree(longitude);
                    if ("W".equals(longitudeRef)) {
                        lon = -lon; // Convert to negative for Western Hemisphere
                    }

                    // Use the latitude and longitude values
                    Log.d("EXIF Data", "Latitude: " + lat + ", Longitude: " + lon);
                } else {
                    Log.d("EXIF Data", "No GPS data available.");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Helper method to convert EXIF GPS coordinates to degrees
    private double convertToDegree(String stringDMS) {
        String[] DMS = stringDMS.split(",", -1);
        String[] dms = DMS[0].split("/", -1);
        double d = Double.parseDouble(dms[0]) / Double.parseDouble(dms[1]);

        String[] minutes = DMS[1].split("/", -1);
        double m = Double.parseDouble(minutes[0]) / Double.parseDouble(minutes[1]);

        String[] seconds = DMS[2].split("/", -1);
        double s = Double.parseDouble(seconds[0]) / Double.parseDouble(seconds[1]);

        return d + (m / 60.0) + (s / 3600.0); // Degrees
    }

//code from AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION"/>

